# How can I get rid of the Google search results snippet prefix "Items 1-30 of ..."?

Tags: category, search, seo

When the Google search results return a Magento shop category it seems to always be prefixed by the term "Items 1-30 of ...".

[image]

It is related to pagination.
If you have less than a full page of products in the category it doesn't appear.

[image]

Any suggestions on how we might get rid of that prefix please?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, Google prefers "all products" pages. But this is murder for shops with large categories of configurable products. Even with a decent template.

Here's the official docs: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2014/02/faceted-navigation-best-and-5-of-worst.html?m=1

Edit:
This is a more complete and comprehensive guide over at [moz](http://moz.com/ugc/seo-guide-to-google-webmaster-recommendations-for-pagination)

Excerpt from conclusion:

> Google clearly favors the View-All page option when the page loads quickly and users can easily find what they are looking for. This means that all items in a paginated series should be listed on the View-All page and all the paginated pages canonical tags to reference the View-All page. The paginated pages in this scenario are there to garner more page views and to make the lists per page more manageable for a user to read. The View-All page is primarily for the search engines.

Comment: I like the "view all" page, I'm not a search engine. Am I...?

Comment: You like it a lot less if it has a large number of configurable products. Pending implementation, the isSaleable() calls will take load times upwards of ten even twenty seconds. Of course, this is largely a design issue: if you have mostly configurable products, use small categories. ;-)

Comment: Any solutions for this?